# How does enterprise library 5.0 silverlight integration pack support WCF RIA logging on the client side?

Tags: silverlight, logging, enterprise-library

I have googled a lot, but still no good examples or any guidance about this, anyone have any good example or other materials to share with? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the feature of logging to isolated storage? Then it's provided. In addition to logging at client side, it also provides logging at server side by WCF logging service and logging to events.

Regarding the resources, the P&P official site is the best one. Please visit http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib5Silverlight&referringTitle=Home for demos, docs and discussions. You can also ask in MS guy's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2011/05/11/silverlight-integration-pack-for-microsoft-enterprise-library-5-0-released.aspx)